# Pinout of Audi 2008 A4 Quattro 3.2L MMI to iPod?

Tags: connector, pinout, ipod

I have came across an Audi A4 2008 Quattro 3.2L, and in the glove compartment it an iPod dock. I took it apart and behind the iPod dock there is a PCB which connects to the ipod connector (which mounnted on another PCB) via 10 pins. This board has the following information:
DEICE42143 V2R6-3 Zold
SNZ0043525 F.-Dat 31/7

The car has a 12-pin connector (only 9 are populated) which is connecting to the above PCB. I looked all over the place for schematics/pinout of this module and did not find any information about it. I just wanted to hack in an AUX to it...

Anyone has any idea how I can figure out which pins are which on the 12 or 10 pin connectors?

Comment: You can look at audi wiring diagram to see which lines are going to the ipod unit. I'm not sure if it would have analog lines or what...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pinout of the iPod 30-pin connector is the starting point from which you might be able to find the audio pins on the car side.

[image]

(Originally from [here](http://linuxslate.org/).  You can also run a google search *iPod 30 pin connector pinout*.)

Comment: For a docking station I found this pinout that made more sense in my case http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-A-N/iPhone_connector_pinout.shtml